# Ansible playbook - to change the line in configuration file

Tags: ansible

I need to write a playbook to replace the line `locking_dir = "/var/lock/lvm"` to `locking_dir = "/run/lock"` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` using ansible

```
/root # cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep locking_dir | grep -v '#'
    locking_dir = "/var/lock/lvm"
```

to

```
locking_dir = "/run/lock"
```

Comment: ansible -m command <cmd>?

Comment: Have you researched the "lineinfile" module?

Answer (score 1):

As an Ad-Hoc command:

```
ansible '<hosts>' -m lineinfile -a "dest=/etc/lvm/lvm.conf backrefs=yes regexp='^(locking_dir)' line='\1 = \"/run/lock\"' state=present"
```

As part of a playbook:

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '^(locking_dir)'
    line: '\1 = \"/run/lock\"'
    state: present
```

I believe `lvm.conf` will have only one line beginning with `locking_dir` so I didn't bother to use a regex to match the complete line. Otherwise the regex would be something like `'^locking_dir = \"/var/lock/lvm\"'`

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
Below playbook got worked for my requirement.

    - name: LVM config
      replace: path=/tmp/lvm.conf
               regexp='locking_dir = "/var/lock/lvm"'
               replace='locking_dir = "/run/lock"'
               backup=yes